# What is the best option for extending the range of the wireless G network?

Tags: wifi

I have an old Microsoft G router and another desktop at the opposite ends of my house. That machine can see the network, but the signal strength is too low for stable connection.

Besides switching to N router, what can be done to extend the range? Maybe some kind of directional antenna?

Edit: It's funny, but the solution was found in the comments to the blog post at the answer's link :) I re-evaluated the possibility of wiring the place, took out my foot-long drill bit, drilled two holes to the attic and one between floors, and now I'm happy with my 80-feet CAT6 ;)

Comment: Ethernet cable is always going to be more stable than wifi (when they are functioning properly)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are  [things to do](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001053.html), and they even look cool ;-)

Answer (score 3):

A wifi repeater is an option
[http://www.amazon.com/Linksys-Wireless-G-Range-Expander-WRE54G/dp/B00021XIJW](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00021XIJW)

Answer (score 1):

Yep, a directional antenna (or even a better omnidirectional antenna) will do wonders for signal strength and link quality.  There's a few different connectors available, and I don't know what a "Microsoft G router" looks like, so I can't give specific recommendations, but the Internet shall provide, no doubt.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Distribution_System

Using the famous Linksys WRT54GL with custom firmware you can very easily setup a WDS network so as to cloud your house.

http://www.polarcloud.com/tomatofaq#how_do_i_use_wds

I used to do this manually (still with WRT54GL's) but now with a pretty AJAX interface it couldn't be easier.

Plus you get excellent http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_of_service with a single tick-box (no need to throttle torrents manually anymore).

2MB Video of the Bandwidth Monitor:http://www.polarcloud.com/v/scbwm.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you into simple hardware hacks check out [Instructables Wireless Hack](http://www.instructables.com/id/WIFI-Antenna-Hack!/). It shows you how to make a simple antenna with the same performance of the $50+ retail extender antennas.